# Run an already defined "Client Report" in the My Client Centre using adwords API

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I am currently researching to no avail if there is any way to "run" a manually created report in the Client Reporting section of the My Client Centre in the Google AdWords with the use of the API.

I am thinking of doing this in PHP as I have most experience in that language, but I dont know if this even can be done.

I have found out that there is a way of defining your own report through .xml and then running that with PHP as a request for a report from the API, but I would really like if I can only get a list of available "Clent Reports" and run that (get a .csv file) through PHP.

So is this even possible? If yes can you please point me to the right direction?

Sorry if this doesn't make sense I am kind of new to AdWords and everything seems so complicated. Let me know if you want some more detail.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible anymore to download reports that were defined in the web interface. But the ad-hoc reporting interface is pretty straight-forward and can easily be accessed using plain synchronous HTTP requests. Have a look at these two documents:

- https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/reporting
- https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/uireports